# How to understand implementation of ntohs?

Tags: assembly

```
(gdb) disas htons
Dump of assembler code for function ntohs:
0x00000037aa4e9470 <ntohs+0>:   ror    $0x8,%di
0x00000037aa4e9474 <ntohs+4>:   movzwl %di,%eax
0x00000037aa4e9477 <ntohs+7>:   retq
```

What does `ror` and `movzwl` do here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`ror` stands for "rotate right", and `movzwl` stands for "move, zero-extending word to long" (for historical reasons dating all the way back to the 8086, in all x86 documentation "words" are only 16 bits).

So:

```
ror     $0x8, %di
```

Rotate the 16-bit value in register `di` (which, on x86-64, contains the first integer argument to a function) right by eight bits; in other words, exchange its high and low bytes.  This is the piece that actually does the job of `ntohs`.

```
movzwl  %di, %eax
```

Copy the 16-bit value in `di` to `eax`, zero-extending it to a 32-bit value.  This instruction is necessary because a function's integer return value goes in `eax`, and if it's shorter than 32 bits, must be extended to 32 bits.

```
retq
```

Return from the function.  (The `q` is just a clue that you're on x86-64.)

Comment: One really weird thing,I'm `disas htons`,why `ntohs` is shown instead?

Comment: And registers on x86-64 are 64-bit,why not extend to 64-bit instead of 32-bit?

Comment: ... I thought that was a typo!  But it's probably because they do exactly the same thing, so somebody figured they could squeeze some extra bytes out of `libc.so` by making `ntohs` and `htons` point to the same code.  As for why not extend to 64-bit, I don't *know* any answer other than "the ABI says you extend to 32-bit", but the original rationale was probably something like `mov[sz]wq` took one more cycle than `mov[sz]wl` on the original x86-64 chips.

Comment: On x64, all operations on 32-bit regs (with a few exceptions) implicitly zero out the top 32 bits of the full 64-bit register. AFAIR this was done to reduce false dependencies on the unused part of the register, so the CPU can do speculative execution more aggressively.

Comment: Zack's correct. `ntohs()` and `htons()` _must_ be equivalent because it's guaranteed that `htons(ntohs(x)) == x` and `ntohs(htons(x)) == x` (i.e. when you convert a value from network to host order and back, you will get your original value again).  
In fact, if your platform uses network (big endian) ordering, then all host-to-net/net-to-host conversion functions are no-ops. On others (like x86/x64), they aren't - but they're still identical.

Comment: @FrankH. (I only just noticed this now) It's true that `ntohs(x) == htons(x)` for all `x`, but that doesn't follow from what you said. `∀x f(g(x)) == g(f(x)) == x` entails only that `g` and `f` are each other's [inverse function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function).  (Your conclusion follows from this *plus* the observation that `ntohs(ntohs(x)) == x`, i.e. byte-swapping is an [involution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involution_%28mathematics%29), since the inverse of any function is unique.)